# Grouping CSS selectors or assigning classes to HTML elements?

Tags: css

When I have to assign a CSS rule to many HTML elements (and that I may constantly change).

I'm always in the dilemma of either grouping CSS selectors:

```
.left-column,
.left-column .post,
.left-column img,
.right-column,
.right-column .post,
.right-column img {
    width: 279px !important;
}
```

Or assinning classes to the HTML elements I want the rule to be applied to (the class name width297 is for reference only. I would never name a class like that):

```
<div id="left-column" class="width279">
 <div id=".post" class="width279">
 </div>
</div>

<div "right-column" class="width279">
</div>

<div class="width279">
</div>

<div class="width279">
```

etc...

What's method would method would save me more time in the long run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method will save you more time. Since you will get in trouble if you want to set something only to the right column and not to the left column.

It's always good to name your field with what they are in CSS since it will be more readable and easier to find.

What if you want to edit your left column? How will you abe able to find it if you name them all like this:

```
<div class="width279">
 <div class="width279">
 </div>
</div>
```

Since you are giving them ID's anyway you might as well style them by ID. Also this style that are the same you can alway use CSS by grouping them:

```
.left-column,
.right-column {
    width: 279px;
}
```

All divs below .left-column and .right-column will inherit the style.